# Not able to stop a JMS consumer in Spring Boot with JmsListenerEndpointRegistry

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jms

**MqStartStopDemoApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MqStartStopDemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private Queue queue;
    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MqStartStopDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, "Hello");
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
        }
    }

}
```

**JMSConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JMSConfig {

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new ActiveMQQueue("simple-jms-queue");
    }

}
```

**Consumer.java**

```
@Component
public class Consumer {

    @JmsListener(destination = "simple-jms-queue")
    public void listener(String msg) {
        System.out.println("Received Message : " + msg);
    }
}
```

**JmsController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/jms")
public class JmsController {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/halt", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String haltJmsListener() {
        JmsListenerEndpointRegistry customRegistry = context.getBean("consumer", JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.class);
        customRegistry.stop();
        return "Jms Listener Stopped";
    }
 ...

}
```

When I run the application and then hit *http://localhost:8080/jms/halt*

**Error Log:**

```
Received Message : Hello
Received Message : Hello
Received Message : Hello
Received Message : Hello
Received Message : Hello
Received Message : Hello
Received Message : Hello
Received Message : Hello
2021-11-02 11:52:12.002  INFO 8804 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-11-02 11:52:12.002  INFO 8804 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-11-02 11:52:12.002  INFO 8804 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
2021-11-02 11:52:12.037 ERROR 8804 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'consumer' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry' but was actually of type 'com.example.demo.Consumer'] with root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'consumer' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry' but was actually of type 'com.example.demo.Consumer'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.adaptBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:417) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:398) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1160) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at com.example.demo.JmsController.haltJmsListener(JmsController.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you think the registry is a bean named `consumer`?

The registry has a reference to each listener container created for each `JmsListener`.

Just use

```
JmsListenerEndpointRegistry customRegistry = context.getBean(JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.class);
```

instead.

The actual bean name is `JmsListenerConfigUtils.JMS_LISTENER_ENDPOINT_REGISTRY_BEAN_NAME` (`"org.springframework.jms.config.internalJmsListenerEndpointRegistry"`).

Comment: Thanks Gary, that worked !

Comment: So Gary, if I had multiple consumers in my app like `OrderConsumer`, `CartConsumer`, how would i stop them individually ? Do I need to extend/implement these Consumers from some class so that `JmsListenerEndpointRegistry`  recognizes and stops them ?

Comment: Consumer are triggered when a new message is detected. You don't need to stop the consumer.

Comment: Give each `@JmsListener` an `id` property and then `registry.getListenerContainer(id).stop()`.

Comment: Excellent, Spring Framework very well thought out and designed :)